# PWA html5 open device camera as soon as page is launched

Tags: html, camera, progressive-web-apps

i have a pwa where i am showing a standard input tag like below. this let user tap on it and get access to device camera. However, i want to open the camera as sooon as you open the webpage. is it possible?

current code:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/gif" capture="camera"/>
```

Comment: That would probably be a security issue. Opening the camera without the user explicitly wanting to. Do any apps (other than camera apps) do that?

Answer (score 1):

Like Mathias said access to the camera is gated behind user permission.
Instead of an input tag like you are using you should really use the Media Capture API.
You have to get the user's permission to access the camera first. Once you have that permission you can connect to the camera and capture photos and video.

Note: Apple has disabled access to camera from homescreen web apps. No idea when they will turn this on. You can access the camera from regular Safari on iOS, just not from a homescreen web app even though it is the same engine.